# Dataweave 2.0 scan regex failure

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I am new to dataweave 2.0 and am trying to use the scan method to extract some text from a string coming back from a http request.

I am trying to extract text with the following regex:

```
\\\"(NewLABEL.[a-z]*)
```

This does what i expect in [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/) and displays the correct selection. However once passed into the scan method like so:

```
$.message scan(/\\\"(NewLABEL.[a-zA-Z]*)/),
```

The full text string is as follows

```
Field \"NewLABEL.title\" of required type \"String!\" was not provided.
```

is returns a blank array.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the input string in a JSON input?

Comment: yes it is. If I remove the \\ it works ish. but i want to target NewLABEL.title. However `NewLABEL` can be different and so can `title`

Answer (score 0):

In JSON quotes inside a string must be escaped with a backlash character `\`. Escaped characters are parsed in memory to their unescaped values. That means that when trying to use the regular expression the escape character will not be present. Try removing it (`\\`) from the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misinterpreting the input string. Tell me one thing, are you getting the "full text string" that you shared in a JSON or a Text? It looks like you are getting a JSON and therefore by looking at it you are thinking that the escape character `\` is also a part of it but it is not.

In other words your string is

```
Field "NewLABEL.title" of required type "String!" was not provided.
```

And not

```
Field \"NewLABEL.title\" of required type \"String!\" was not provided.
```

If your string was the later one the regex will work. 
You can try this

```
'Field \"NewLABEL.title\" of required type \"String!\" was not provided.'
scan /\\\"(NewLABEL.[a-zA-Z]*)/
```

and it will work. Because in this the string is wrapped within single quotes and therefore your string this time will actually have the `\` in it. If you wrap the same in `"` it won't work cause the `\"` will actually mean `"` only